# Nodejs readFile get content

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get content from:

```
fs.readFile('./access.log', function read(err, data) {
var content = data.toString();
});
```

I need to use it in other function.

When I tried like this:

```
var content;
fs.readFile('./access.log', function read(err, data) {
content = data.toString();
});

console.log("Content: " + content);
```

It shows that content is undefined.

Comment: You cannot treat asynchronous functions as though they are synchronous. This has been discussed ad nausem with regard to node. Try searching on here and google and you will find many, *many* results.

Comment: ./access.log file location not accesible

Comment: I checked and when i put console.log(content) to function, it shows the content of this file

Comment: put console.log(content);   inside fs.readFile(){}//BLOCK

Comment: your console.log(content) is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is defined in an asynchronous way and designed to be invoked in parallel but you have no invocation criteria.  Instead run `fs.readFileSync` which will run the method now in a synchronous way:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
var text = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/access.log', 'utf8'); 
console.log({text});   //prints content of file.
```

Source: reading files with NodeJS: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs